# How to stop applets from being blocked by Java

Tags: java, html

I am making an applet right now, and I am trying to upload the file to my website. I uploaded the .class file and wrote the HTML code for it:

```
<applet codebase="example.com/files/" code="test.class">
</applet>
```

After I put it on my site and publish it then run it, it tells me that Java blocked it. I wanted to know how I can prevent Java from blocking the applets that I make for myself and also other people.

Do I also need a certification and how do I get it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using applets? are you from the past?

Comment: I don't think Java's blocking it, but your browser probably is

Comment: You might want to look into signing the applets. Or possibly look into Java Web Start.

Comment: Applets have some security issues, that's the reason almost all the browsers are blocking all the applets by default,  you need to change the configuration in your browser and change the java configuration in your (client) machine.

Comment: @luisZavaleta What do you mean? What do people use nowadays?

Comment: @bijx it depends, but  HTML5/ajax/json is a good option.

Comment: Or at least javaFX, but I don't see any future in that.

Comment: Or even Java Web Start

Comment: @luisZavaleta I would argue that technologies like JavaFX and Flash bring a well known API which just works, with browser compatibility still a major thorn in the side of web developers, it's unlikely that we'll see and end to these technologies, just saying ;)